# get relative parent ignoring child margin

Tags: javascript, html, css

To make it short, this is my DOM:

```
<div class="markable_wrapper">
    <span class="marker_label"></span>
    <span class="markable ">&nbsp;</span>
</div>

<div class="markable_wrapper">
    <span class="marker_label"></span>
    <span class="markable second_box">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Too see its appearance including the CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/6cg89/3/

I need the red triangle to appear in the right upper corner while the parent container ignores the boxes margin (due to dynamic positioned elements like the second box). Is there a way to handle this in CSS only?

**Keep in mind** that i can not change the boxes margin and i also cant nest the spans because in many cases its a textarea or something else.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is jQuery an option to work with? could you please post a picture of what it should look like at the end!?

Comment: i updated the fiddle including a box how it should look like finally: http://jsfiddle.net/6cg89/2/
Remember - i cant change the boxes margin.

If possible anyhow i'd like to avoid using javascript for this, since this affects many elements where some of them may change its size on window-resizing which will result in a lots of work to do (for javascript) beside the existing mighty JS on the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If pseudo elements are an option, because it's not clear from your requirements, you can dispense with the 'marker span' completely.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6cg89/5/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="markable_wrapper">
    <span class="markable ">&nbsp;</span>
</div>

<div class="markable_wrapper">
    <span class="markable second_box">&nbsp;</span>
</div>

<!-- This is how it should looks like: -->

<div class="markable_wrapper">
    <span class="markable third_box">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.markable_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.markable {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: 15px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.markable:after {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) #F00 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    top:-1px;
    left:100%;
    margin-left: -7px;
}

.second_box {
    margin-right: 50px;
}
.third_box {
    margin-right: 0;
```

}

Comment: This looks great but another problem to deal with - the triangle must be clickable to load additional information (like excel-comments) thats why i had to use that fancy border-technique to make the click through the triangle element (outside the coloured triangle) possible the easy way..

Comment: Ah...that's a little trickier as it's styling only so it's not clickable.

Comment: Nope...it's not in the DOM so it's not selectable by JS/JQ (AFAIK).

Answer (score 1):

If your `markable` element have fixed widths, you can set the `left` attribute of the `markable_label` instead of the right :

```
.markable_label {
    position: absolute ;
    left: 44px ; /* Width of markable - Width of markable_label */
}
```

If you know the margin of `markable`, you can set the `right` attribute :

```
.markable_label {
    position: absolute ;
    right: 47px;  /* Margin right - half the width of triangle. */
}
```

If you're generating you code with PHP or other stuff, and you either know the `width` or `margin-right`, you can infer the `left` or `right` attribute of your `markable_label`. If not, you'll have to use javascript to detect `width` / `margin` and set `left` / `right` attributes.

Comment: Thanks. The problem here is that the boxes can be different. I updated the fiddle to show you what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/6cg89/3/

Since the width and the margin are dynamic depending on the element (and may even change on window-resizing) this would take me down to use javascript for this - which i'd like to avoid using it if there's any css-solution.

Comment: @xcy7e Yes it is what I thought but if you know the box width in advance (I don't know what you're using server side), you can infer margin-left. If you don't, you'll have to use javascript to detect width / height.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't there any solution changing the wrappers Style-Attributes that way it (kind of) ignores the margin (dynamically)

Comment: @xcy7e Trying some stuff, I came to that : http://jsfiddle.net/BjQQ4/. Edit: It's almost the same answer as Paulie_D.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have a margin in `.markable` and `.second_box`? There are a 15px and 50px margin respectively.

If you remove the margins, and then add `right: -3px;` to the `.marker_label` then it will be positionated right in the upper right corner.

`NOTE:` you have to give -3px because it's half of the width you added with borders (borders expands width half inside and half outside

Comment: Yes i need the (dynamic) margin. Imagine the triangle to appears on several different (types of) elements on the page that are positioned in many different ways.